# Get list of users that use my facebook app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have found that there is a way to find which of my friends are the users of my facebook app.

```
$retrobj=$facebook->api(array('method' => 'fql.query', 'query' =>
"SELECT name FROM user WHERE is_app_user = '1' AND uid IN (SELECT uid2
 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = '" . $user. "')"));
```

The above query will show which of my friends uid use my app.

Then i use a while loop to parse through the returned array.

My question is the following...

If i do not have their id's, is there a way to get all the users even if they are not my friends that use my app?

I haven't found a way that is why i am asking if there is actually a way to do that.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Facebook found that some developers were building apps just to harvest Facebook usernames, and spam them. They removed the ability to return a list of app and page users.

Any FQL query you run must have one of the indexed fields (marked with a star) in your `WHERE` clause, or the query will fail. That requires a `name`, `username` or `user_id`. Querying the `friend`, `event_member`, `stream` or `checkin` tables are a few of the valid ways to get a list of other users.

Comment: does this still hold @cpilko?